# Einstein Dataset Creation issue - Invalid File Format

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, trailhead, einstein

I am trying to create a dataset and train as per the below trailhead topic(https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/build-a-cat-rescue-app-that-recognizes-cat-breeds/cat-recognition-app-create-train-dataset)

I have created a new folder with other images and trying to upload those images from Files, Documents & Static Resource in salesforce, but all getting failed with "Invalid file format" issue.

[image]

All of the images in that folder are in "PNG" format.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you provide for "Create Dataset" needs to be publicly accessible.

The sample URL of https://developer.salesforce.com/files/Cats.zip is something that the Einstein Platform API services can ingest with a GET request and no authentication required.

If you want to use your own zip file it will need to be opened up to the internet. Or at least to the [Metadata servers](https://metamind.readme.io/). The Apex wrapper used for this is calling the [Create a Dataset From a Zip File Asynchronously](https://metamind.readme.io/docs/create-a-dataset-zip-async) method.